# Centos Kernel Update - unknown bash script

Tags: shell-script, centos

Is it ok to run the script below on CentOS 7?

```bash
wget -N --no-check-certificate https://github.com/teddysun/across/raw/master/bbr.sh && chmod +x bbr.sh && bash bbr.sh
```

It seems it is for update kernel.
But i am a bit of scared about patch kernel of os.

Comment: It's for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This depends how much you trust GitHub user *teddysun* to write scripts which are not harmful and not bugged. Without reading the `bbr.sh` script, it's impossible to tell what it will do.

Generally, there is always a risk in running scripts taken from the Internet on your machine. In case of reputable vendors, or reputable people, this is mostly fine.